# How do I solve mysql kivy operator validation problem:

Tags: python, kivy

Below is the error I get from python kivy codes. Kindly help me solve this issue. I actually want to access my database stocks from the operator window using MySQl commands.

line 41, in update_purchases
target_code = self.stocks.find_one({'product_code': pcode})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_one'

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import mysql.connector
import re
from kivy.lang import Builder


class OperatorWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='Livingstone2#',
            database='pos'
        )
        self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
      

        self.stocks = ''
        self.cart = []
        self.qty = []
        self.total = 0.00

    def logout(self):
        self.parent.parent.current = 'scrn_si'

    def update_purchases(self):
        pcode = self.ids.code_inp.text
        products_container = self.ids.products
        #target_code = self.mycursor.fetchall({'product_code': pcode})
        target_code = self.stocks.find_one({'product_code': pcode})
        if target_code == None:
            pass
        else:
            details = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=None, height=30, pos_hint={'top': 
            1})
            products_container.add_widget(details)

            code = Label(text=pcode, size_hint_x=.2, color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            name = Label(text=target_code['product_name'], size_hint_x=.3, 
            color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            qty = Label(text='1', size_hint_x=.1, color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            disc = Label(text='0.00', size_hint_x=.1, color=(.06, .45, .45, 
            1))
            price = Label(text=target_code['product_price'], size_hint_x=.1, 
            color=(.06, .45, .45, 1))
            total = Label(text='0.00', size_hint_x=.2, color=(.06, .45, .45, 
            1))
            details.add_widget(code)
            details.add_widget(name)
            details.add_widget(qty)
            details.add_widget(disc)
            details.add_widget(price)
            details.add_widget(total)

            #Update Preview
            pname = name.text
            pprice = float(price.text)
            pqty = str(1)
            self.total += pprice
            purchase_total = '`\n\nTotal\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'+str(self.total)
            self.ids.cur_product.text = pname
            self.ids.cur_price.text = str(pprice)
            preview = self.ids.receipt_preview
            prev_text = preview.text
            _prev = prev_text.find('`')
            if _prev >0:
                prev_text = prev_text[:_prev]

            ptarget = -1
            for i, c in enumerate(self.cart):
                if c == pcode:
                    ptarget = i

            if ptarget >= 0:
                pqty = self.qty[ptarget]+1
                self.qty[ptarget] = pqty
                expr = '%s\t\tx\d\t' % (pname)
                rexpr = pname + '\t\tx' + str(pqty)+'\t'
                nu_text = re.sub(expr, rexpr, prev_text)
                preview.text = nu_text + purchase_total
            else:
                self.cart.append(pcode)
                self.qty.append(1)
                nu_preview = '\n'.join([prev_text, pname + '\t\tx' + pqty + 
        '\t\t' + str(pprice), purchase_total])
                preview.text = nu_preview

        self.ids.disc_input.text = '0.00'
        self.ids.disc_perc_input.text = '0.00'
        self.ids.qty_input.text = str(pqty)
        self.ids.price_input.text = str(pprice)
        self.ids.vat_input.text = '15%'
        self.ids.total_input.text = str(pprice)
```

Comment: You have added your code right before I published my answer. I can see two things in here. First, you are not executing any query to the database, just trying to retrieve results. Second, that code is retrieving results from a database from inside a view class, which doesn't follow a good programming model.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the method `fetchall` is being called with two positional arguments when it only requires one.

But where is the second argument in the following line?

```
 target_code = self.mycursor.fetchall({'product_code': pcode})
```

Well, the second argument is the dictionary `{'product_code': pcode}`. The first one is the object's `self`. I recommend you read [this article](https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why) in order to better understand it but the thing is that each class' method needs a reference to the object in order to know who is executing a method. That reference is `self`.

Notice in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) how the method `fetchall` is not accepting any other positional argument. The solution is to fetch all the rows with the following line:

```
 target_code = self.mycursor.fetchall()
```

Finally, noticing the dictionary you were passing to `fetchall`, maybe you intended to use that on [`execute`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), which would use it to set the value `pcode` inside the query before running it.